# How do I fix the display of Windows 7's Control Panel?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, control-panel

This has really bugged me since I took the plunge and upgraded to Windows 7.  I think everything is great on the whole apart from the Control Panel.

Instead of ordering from **top to bottom** like in normal folders, it is ordered from **left to right**.  Whenever I go to find something in Control Panel it takes 3 times as long because I expect to find Programs and Features below Power Options yet it is to the right.

This is a screenshot to demonstrate - note the ordering goes across instead of down.

[image]

Does anyone have a cunning fix to display the Control Panel ordered in the same way that normal folders are displayed?

Comment: My advice to you is to get used to using the fantastic Start Menu search feature instead of hunting for icons. You want Programs and Features? Simply press the Start button, type "programs" and there it is.

Comment: Same advice to anyone else with a similar moan.  Using the Start orb thingy really is the way forward.  So much quicker.

Comment: @OverloadUT You can also launch the Programs by typing appwiz.cpl

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The **Control Panel** uses **Tiles View** to display the items. **Tiles View** is left to right and is default behavior (In fact, **Icons (Small/Large) View** is left to right too)

Unfortunately, there is no way to tell the control panel to use **List View**, which is what you seem to want. (Only **List View**, **Details View** and **Content View** is top to bottom).

Comment: +1 that's correct, complaints about this emerged right from the first test releases but as usual, Microsoft din't care much for user input/feedback, what's new? :)

Comment: ahh, microsoft innovation at its finest. :)

Answer (score 6):

The left to right ordering in the W7 Control Panel is excruciatingly annoying. I looked around for a W7 tweaking tool that might present a different CP view and didn't see anything.

So, I put together a folder of shortcuts of W7 CP items, which can in fact be ordered any way one likes, since it's just an ordinary folder. I set the "Comment" fields of the shortcuts to match the roll-over text of the actual Control Panel items, so when the folder Comment column is enabled, the list of shortcuts look a lot like the XP/Vista CP details view.

This folder of W7 shortcuts can be downloaded here:

[W7 Shortcuts Folder Download](http://reliancepc.com/menu/tips/Downloads/W7ListViewControlPanel.exe)

The downloaded file is a self-extracting 7z bundle that outputs the folder "W7 ListView Control Panel"

Comment: Interesting workaround creating a folder of shortcuts which can then be ordered.  I like it, thanks.

Comment: Great workaround! I wonder whether the OP saw your answer before he gave the other answer the status Accepted Answer. I replaced the Control Panel shortcut in the Start Menu with your shortcut, and it's just like in the good old days!

Answer (score 2):

Hey, I found a solution!  Simply make your Control Panel window's horizontal dimensions smaller (i.e. make your control panel tall and skinny).  Now there is no annoying left-right ordering because you have a single column of icons listed in alphabetical order, which you can easily scroll up and down.

Comment: Hardly a 'fix', just a workaround!

Comment: This is actually the best solution available next to having to download something.  Edit:  Well, maybe not.  Making the window thinner works at first, but then you have to widen it again to see the contents o after the window is loaded with whatever it was you clicked on (list of programs for example).